# How can I change certain parts to lowercase and without spaces?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, spaces, lowercase

I got this far to print out the info as I want it to on the page (this is just for my own personal use) as a generator to speed things up for me. But I would like to get one part to remove any spaces between the form entries, and to change to lower case.
Example, when it displays #Korn interview Last Year
I would like it to instead show #korninterviewlastyear
But only in that part that is generating the hashtags

MANY THANKS for any and all help. It's greatly appreciated.

Everything else is just fine to what I'm wanting to accomplish

```
<font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
<style>
#entries,#results{float:left}
</style>
</font>
<div id="entries"> 
  <form name ="myform">
    <p><font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Band: 
      <input type="text" name="band"/>
      <br>
      Song: 
      <input type="text" name="song"/>
      <br>
      Title: 
      <input type="text" name="title"/>
      <br>
      YT Link: 
      <input type="text" name="link"/>
      <br>
      <input type="hidden" name="disc" value="*Copyright Disclaimer Under Section 107 of the Copyright Act of 1976, allowance is made for 'fair use' for purposes such as criticism, comment, news reporting, teaching, scholarship, and research. Fair use is a use permitted by copyright statute that might otherwise be infringing. Non-profit, educational or personal use tips the balance in favor of fair use. No copyright infringement intended. ALL RIGHTS BELONG TO THEIR RESPECTIVE OWNERS*"/>
      <br>
      <input type="hidden" name="comma" value=","/>
      <br>
      <input type="button" value="display" onclick="collect(this.form)"/>
      </font></p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p><font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">__________________ </font></p>
  </form>
</div>
<div id="results"></div>
<p> <font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
  <script type="text/javascript">
function collect(frm) { 
document.getElementById("results").innerHTML+=" #"+frm.band.value+" #"+frm.song.value+" #reaction<br><br>Thanks for the subs and views. Lets hit a Million this year!<br><br>Link If You Would Like To Contribute: http://www.peredyrock.com/reactions<br><br>Link to original video: "+frm.link.value+"<br><br>Click Here To Subscribe! https://www.youtube.com/peredymusic<br><br>All of my videos: https://www.youtube.com/peredymusic<br><br>Peredy Channel Merch: https://shop.spreadshirt.com/peredyytmerch<br><br><br><br>"+frm.disc.value+"<br><br><br><br>#"+frm.band.value+" #"+frm.band.value+"once #"+frm.song.value+" #"+frm.song.value+"video #musicvideo #live #official #video #metalheadreaction #youtube #peredyreactions #peredy #firsttime #once #rock #pop #goth #metal #metalhead #music #reaction #metalreaction #youtube #peredyreacts<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>"+frm.band.value+""+frm.comma.value+""+frm.song.value+""+frm.comma.value+""+frm.title.value+""+frm.comma.value+""+frm.title.value+" "+frm.band.value+" reaction"+frm.comma.value+""+frm.band.value+" "+frm.song.value+""+frm.comma.value+""+frm.band.value+" "+frm.song.value+" official"+frm.comma.value+""+frm.band.value+" "+frm.song.value+" reaction"+frm.comma.value+""+frm.song.value+" reaction"+frm.comma.value+""+frm.band.value+" "+frm.song.value+" live reaction"+frm.comma.value+""+frm.song.value+" live reaction"+frm.comma.value+""+frm.band.value+" live reaction"+frm.comma.value+""+frm.band.value+" "+frm.song.value+" official"+frm.comma.value+""+frm.band.value+" "+frm.song.value+" live"+frm.comma.value+"official live reaction"+frm.comma.value+"gothic metal reaction"+frm.comma.value+"goth metal reaction"+frm.comma.value+"rock reaction"+frm.comma.value+"peredy"+frm.comma.value+"metal reaction"+frm.comma.value+"metal head reaction"+frm.comma.value+"peredy reacts"+frm.comma.value+"<hr>"
frm.reset();
} 
</script>
  </font></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Comment: user [string replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method and [string toLowerCase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) method ... `yourstring.toLowercase().replace(/\s+/g, '')`

Comment: Thank you very much. Would I put that right before the document.getElementById("results")?

Comment: you put it where it needs to go - I haven't read your code at all

Answer (score -1):

This is how I would do it:

```js
function collect(frm) { 
  document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += "#" + [frm.band.value, frm.song.value].join('').toLowerCase() /* + whatever else you need here... */;
}
```

You'd probably also want to get rid of punctuation, so you could use the `String.prototype.replace()` function to replace whatever pattern to a string of your liking.

Also, I suggest switching to concatenating strings using the newer string interpolation syntax:

```js
`#${[frm.band.value, frm.song.value].join('').toLowerCase()}`
```

Comment: you'd combine the two "hastags" into one? that's not what the question is asking for

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific. I need the forced lowercase and space removal for only this section (and just for the "+frm...values)
 <br><br><br><br>#"+frm.band.value+" #"+frm.band.value+"once #"+frm.song.value+" #"+frm.song.value+"video #musicvideo #live #official #video #metalheadreaction #youtube #peredyreactions #peredy #firsttime #once #rock #pop #goth #metal #metalhead #music #reaction #metalreaction #youtube #peredyreacts<br><br>

Comment: @JaromandaX Forgive me for not 100% understanding the code of the `collect()` function which is way too long and not too readable. Edit: @Peredy's edit made it more clear.

Comment: @Peredy so the hashtag needs to be a join of which strings exactly?

Comment: I put the hashtag to make those print as hashtags when displayed. So that part is working. But for example, if put in the song was "It Is Time" then it will display #It Is Time, instead of #itistime. I need it to convert to the second one, #itistime, but just for those that have the hashtag, and the rest left as is

Comment: @AmitBeckenstein - you do not need forgiveness - I just pointed out an error in your assumption ... I didn't even bother reading the code until you posted :p

Comment: I don't suppose I could just send someone like 20 bucks to make this work could I? Haha. I found lots of info but I can't seem to make it work. I should note that I'm not a code developer at all. I'm just making this for one function for myself.

Comment: @AmitBeckenstein I tried the suggestion  multiple places but I can't seem to get it to work. But, I'm not at all a coder or anything. I just wanted to make this one page project for my own use so I found this online and changed it up. But this last part I can't make happen. Humbly, I have $19.36 in my paypal. It's yours if you can make it work. It's not a lot I know. Here is a link to a pic of what I need changed to kill the spaces and punctuation (Caps can stay, lowercase not needed anymore) I highlighted the parts that only should chang

http://www.peredyrock.com/reactions/scriptsample.png